# How to download files from authenticate required Jenkins job workspace via command line

Tags: jenkins

How to do it if:

- Jenkins server need log in first before access anything. Anonymous user has no read access
- From a Linux bash in another machine (or Windows cmd)

Answer (score 3):

The Jenkins supports basic authentication. So you can specify your username and password in the command for basic authentication, like below with `curl`:

```
curl -u your_username:your_password http://<your_jenkins_host>/job/<job_name>/<job_id>/artifact/<file_name>
```